# Outlook email engine is adding extra padding

Tags: outlook, html-email, padding

i am tryin to create a html email template which is working fine in almost all client , except the outlook desktop.
i tried most of the thread solution related to this but i am not able to find the exact issue .

```
<body  width="100%" style="margin: 0; line-height: 1.4; font:normal 10pt Open Sans; background:#e0e0e0;">
    <table align="center" style="border-collapse: separate;">
      <tr>
         <td>
          <table style="padding:25px; background:#ffffff; width:800">     
            <tr>
                <td  style="color:#000000; font-size:29px; font-weight:400; text-align:center">
                email header
                </td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td  style="border: solid 5px #ffffff"></td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td > message <a href="${wacUrl}" style="color:#5F259F; font-weight:500;font-weight:bold;" target="_blank"> hyperlink to website </a>.
</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  style="border: solid 5px #ffffff"></td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  style="font-weight:bold;" >order header </td>
            </tr>
           </table>
          </td> 
      </tr>
    </table>
<body>
```

this works fine in all client except outlook desktop, which add extra padding putting one row as example

```
    <tr>
      <td style='padding:18.75pt 18.75pt 18.75pt 18.75pt'>
          <p class=MsoNormal>
              <b>
                  <span style='color:black'>Order header
                  </span>
              </b>
              <b>
                  <o:p>
                  </o:p>
              </b>
          </p>
      </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Try adding padding 0pt to each of that td in that table and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities that come to mind immediately:

- margins on elements
- padding on elements
- line-height on elements

In order to confirm what was causing this, I changed the background colors and border colors in outlook to see what was going on and included the screenshots of what's happening below for your reference.

## Fix

Based on what I'm seeing here, I think putting the `padding:25px;` in the content table's inline styles is causing all of the cells within the table to have a default padding of 25px. So I've moved the padding, background, and width for the table to the cell that contains the content table in order to fix that.

Here's the updated code with a screenshot of the result in litmus previews of outlook:

```
<body width="100%" style="margin: 0; line-height: 1.4; font:normal 10pt Open Sans; background:#e0e0e0;">
    <table align="center" style="border-collapse: separate;">
        <tr>
            <td style="background:#ffffff; padding:25px; width:800;">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="color:#000000; font-size:29px; font-weight:400; text-align:center">
                        email header
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="border: solid 5px #ffffff"></td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        message <a href="${wacUrl}" style="color:#5F259F; font-weight:500;font-weight:bold;"  target="_blank"> hyperlink to website </a>.
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="border: solid 5px #ffffff"></td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-weight:bold;" >order header </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<body>
```

Screenshot of fixed code in outlook litmus previews
[image: outlook litmus preview of fixed code]

---

### Reference Screenshots

Here are screenshots of the results in the web preview vs. the outlook preview in litmus for your reference:

| web browser | outlook litmus |
| --- | --- |
| [image: web browser preview] | [image: outlook litmus preview] |

After removing cellpadding and cellspacing as well as setting border to 0 on the table that has the content in cells:

| web browser | outlook litmus |
| --- | --- |
| [image: web browser preview with borders, cellpadding, and cellspacing set to 0] | [image: outlook litmus preview with borders, cellpadding, and cellspacing set to 0] |

After removing `padding:25px;` on the table that has the cell content this is what I got:

[image: outlook preview with table padding removed]